# HTTP to JMS Bridge

Tags: http, jms, soa, esb

### Overview

I'd like to expose a message queue to the internet so that client applications can communicate with some of our back-end services.

I don't want to expose the jms endpoint directly because of sercurity reasons.  Also, a plain HTTP transport would obviate the need to distribute jms plugins to heterogeneous client applications (.net, java, javascript).

### Research Findings

#### ActiveMQ

I've taken a look at ActiveMQ's "built-in" REST interface:

http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html

But in testing, I found the demo to be unreliable *(i.e. "Where did my messages go?")*.  Also, it wasn't well documented on how to pull the demo out into a "real" implementation.

#### ESB

Since this is sounds like a classic "Bridge" pattern in enterprise integration patterns, I looked that the major open-source ESB/SOA integration engines:

- Spring Integration
- Mule
- ServiceMix

Of the three, the clearest piece of documentation seems to be [ServiceMix's](http://servicemix.apache.org/creating-a-protocol-bridge.html) which offers a In-only message pattern, I would require both POST-ing and GET-ing messages.

Unfortunately for terms of evaluation, it seems like I would have to a deep-dive into each implementation and configuration.  I realize that an out-of-the-box setup may be too much to ask, but I'd rather not learn all three just to which one fits my needs the best. So...

### Questions

- Have you implemented a similar architecture?  What did you use?
- Regardless of the first answer which would you suggest now?
- Which is simplest?

Comment: I have create an ESB that provides a javascript api that uses rest, it should be possible to have a client that subscribe to a queue such as rabbitmq and use the javascript api to read messages without exposing much information about the queue itself. And example is this app that uses the javascript api:  http://tinyurl.com/3bmr4z8

Answer (score 5):

You could always check out the [Apache Camel Project](http://camel.apache.org/).
It allows you to expose and route requests from Http, Web Services, etc to a JMS queue.

Although I voted for Will's answer. The servlet is really the way to go here.

Comment: ActiveMQ actually comes bundled with Camel.  The full ActiveMQ examples requires you to get into the ActiveMQ, Jetty and Camel configurations.  ServiceMix uses ActiveMQ.  The Apache chain is a little hard to figure out what the smallest component to nicely solve the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could write a servlet and do this in a couple dozen lines of code.

Comment: I considered that, and that's what I may wind up doing, but another servlet written means another servlet I need to maintain.  :)

Comment: vs. how many megs of server infrastructure that you have pretty much no control over or knowledge of.

Comment: true, but "simple" servlets have a nasty tendency to grow into non-trivial servlets.  For example, implementing url-mapping to different queues and setting up synchronous replies and asynchronous reply-tos pushes us past the "simple" 20 line mark.

Comment: Eh, most of the flexibility for these systems stems from 5% edge cases, which makes them over complicated for 95% if the edge cases. If you're in the 5%, then off you go then and track one of these systems down. Otherwise you can code it and be done with it, change it when necessary, and incrementally improve it if, and when, your use case changes. A simple map can handle your routing, and Servlet 3.0 and Comet processing is well documented with simple examples for the rest if you actually need to go that far.

Comment: I completely agree (which is why I've up-voted you so far), but there's a fine line between not-built-here syndrome and 'overkill framework' syndrome.  Anyway this 'build-it/buy-it' discussion is good to have to see what other people would do.

Comment: Of course, I just happen to see a lot of folks turning to these pre-made solution for ostensibly simple problems. Folks just need to be honest with their requirements, and realize that adopting these systems also come with a cost.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similiar goal, exposing a lightweight http resource for clients. It actually acts as adapter that takes simple textmessages and puts them simply asynchronous to a queue, for later processing. My research results so far (only additions to the existing answers):

- HornetQ REST

  Good, but the calles has to know the destination name, which is undesired for my usecase.
  [Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html)
- HJB (HTTP JMS Bridge)

  Also didn't fits my needs, beside of this the documentation is not good to understand, it is also not longer maintained.
  [Website](http://hjb.berlios.de/)

I probably end up writing my own adapter, either using some thin servlet/etc. or Apache Camel.